# JavaScript loop random pick from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am having a problem with this. I want to pick random word from an array everytime the popup loads. But the word doesn't change. I always get results as:

```
(march, march, march.. january, january, january, january, january)...
```

It just pick the random month and then uses it every loop. I want to make it random every loop. Can someone please help me?

```js
var i;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  $("#notification").fadeIn("slow").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");

  var myArray = ['January', 'February', 'March'];
  var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

  document.getElementById("notification").innerHTML = rand;
}

//$("#notification").append(rand);
```

```css
#notification {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 170px;
  /* set to 100% if space is available */
  height: 70px;
  z-index: 105;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #FF7800;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #222;
  padding: 5px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

#notification span.dismiss {
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  padding: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#notification a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notification" style="display: none;">
  <span class="dismiss"><a title="dismiss this notification">X</a></span>
</div>
```

JSfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Sumba/vmsb14dL/)

Comment: You should not perform asynchronous operations (showing/hiding the element with animations) in a synchronous loop. That will result in unwanted behaviour.

Comment: so what do i do? im desperate, really

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop completes immediately before the animation starts, so you're seeing the last generated random value only.

Instead, you need to wait each time for the animation to complete before making the next iteration. This you can do with a callback argument to `fadeOut`:

```js
var myArray = ['January', 'February', 'March']; 
(function loop(i) { 
   if (i >= 5) return; // all iterations have been completed
   var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
   document.getElementById("notification").textContent = rand;
   // Use callback argument of fadeOut to chain to next iteration
   //    when the animation is complete
   $("#notification").fadeIn("slow").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow", loop.bind(null, i+1));
})(0); // Execute the loop function immediately with i = 0
```

```css
#notification {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    width:170px; /* set to 100% if space is available */
    height: 70px;
    z-index:105;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:12px;
    color:white;
    background-color:#FF7800;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #222;
    padding:5px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
#notification span.dismiss {
    border:2px solid #FFF;
    padding:0 5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:right;
    margin-right:10px;
}
#notification a {
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notification" style="display: none;">
  <span class="dismiss"><a title="dismiss this notification">X</a></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You add a delay for animation via for loops.

However, all random value calculated at the first tick.

```
var i;
var myArray = ['January', 'February', 'March','April','May']; 
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
$("#notification").fadeIn("slow").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");

setTimeout(function(){
var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
  document.getElementById("notification").innerHTML = rand;
  // slow refer to 600ms, 600*2+1000 = 2200
  },2200*i);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vmsb14dL/81/